# How to resolve Subquery returning more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, subquery

I know that there are lots of these questions, but I was unable to find a definitive answer elsewhere.

I have 4 tables:

- person_per
- person2group2role_p2g2r
- group_grp
- list_lst

I am wanting to run a query which shows all the information about a person, including the group types they are in

The `per_ID` is in the `person_per` table

The many-to-many bridge has the `per_ID`, `grp_ID` and `role_ID`

the `grp_ID` is in the `group_grp` table

the `grp_type` in the `group_grp` table links with the `lst_optionID`

the `lst_OptionName` is the name in text (what i finally want displayed)

I tried doing it in two ways, hitting the same error in both. Option 1 uses `WHERE` args to link tables whereas Option 2 uses `JOIN` statements.
This is all in the second subquery. The main query is pulling personal information and the first subquery is pulling the classification of the person.

#### Option 1:

```
SELECT person_per.per_ID as AddToCart, CONCAT(person_per.per_FirstName, ' ', person_per.per_MiddleName) AS 'FirstNames', person_per.per_LastName AS 'Surname', 
    (SELECT lst_OptionName FROM list_lst WHERE list_lst.lst_ID=1 AND
        list_lst.lst_OptionID=person_per.per_cls_ID) AS "Classification",
    person_per.per_HomePhone AS 'Tel', person_per.per_WorkPhone AS 'Cell',
    person_per.per_Email AS 'Email',
    --START DIFF
    (SELECT lst_OptionName 
    FROM list_lst, person2group2role_p2g2r, group_grp, person_per 
    WHERE list_lst.lst_ID=3 
        AND person_per.per_ID = person2group2role_p2g2r.p2g2r_per_ID 
        AND person2group2role_p2g2r.p2g2r_grp_ID = group_grp.grp_ID 
        AND group_grp.grp_Type = list_lst.lst_ID) AS "LifeGroupType"
    --END DIFF
FROM person_per
ORDER BY person_per.per_LastName
```

#### Option 2:

```
SELECT person_per.per_ID as AddToCart, CONCAT(person_per.per_FirstName, ' ', person_per.per_MiddleName) AS 'FirstNames', person_per.per_LastName AS 'Surname',
    (SELECT lst_OptionName FROM list_lst WHERE list_lst.lst_ID=1 AND
        list_lst.lst_OptionID=person_per.per_cls_ID) AS "Classification",
    person_per.per_HomePhone AS 'Tel', person_per.per_WorkPhone AS 'Cell',
    person_per.per_Email AS 'Email',
    --START DIFF
    (SELECT lst_OptionName 
    FROM list_lst 
        JOIN group_grp ON group_grp.grp_Type = list_lst.lst_ID
        JOIN person2group2role_p2g2r ON person2group2role_p2g2r.p2g2r_grp_ID = group_grp.grp_ID
        JOIN person_per ON person_per.per_ID = person2group2role_p2g2r.p2g2r_per_ID
    WHERE list_lst.lst_ID=3) AS "LifeGroupType"
    --END DIFF
FROM person_per
ORDER BY person_per.per_LastName
```

I understand that this is an issue because each person can be assigned to multiple groups, I was just wondering how I can split the different groups up.
Preferable outcome would be a single row per person with all their info and the groups they are in.
Otherwise how would I

1. CONCAT the multiple sub-query results into a single field
2. Have a different Line for the person's different group

Any info would be amazing :)

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume the problem is that the subqueries are returning more than one row, because people have more than one item in each table.  Then, I'm going to assume that you are using MySQL.  The solution is a function called `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT p.per_ID as AddToCart, CONCAT(p.per_FirstName, ' ', p.per_MiddleName) AS FirstNames, 
       p.per_LastName AS Surname, 
       (SELECT group_concat(lst_OptionName)
        FROM list_lst l
        WHERE l.lst_ID = 1 AND l.lst_OptionID = p.per_cls_ID
       ) AS Classification,
       p.per_HomePhone AS Tel, p.per_WorkPhone AS Cell, p.per_Email AS Email,
    --START DIFF
       (SELECT lst_OptionName 
        FROM person2group2role_p2g2r p2g join
             group_grp g
             on p2g.p2g2r_grp_ID = g.grp_ID join
             list_lst l
             on g.grp_Type = l.lst_ID
        WHERE l.lst_ID = 3 and p.per_ID = p2g.p2g2r_per_ID
       ) AS LifeGroupType
    --END DIFF
FROM person_per p
ORDER BY p.per_LastName;
```

Along the way, I also added table aliases to make the query more readable, explicit `join` syntax, and removed the extra unnecessary reference to `person_per` in the subquery.  That might have been the cause of your problem in the first place.

Comment: Just the second subquery is returning multiple rows.
Indeed, using MySQL, sorry about that.
Can you explain the "p2g" in the second subquery. If I use this code it gives errors on the group_grp g. I'm assuming this is because of that "p2g"
Thanks for cleaning it up though!

Comment: The `p2g` is a table alias, an abbreviation that in general makes queries easier to read and is mandated in some circumstances.  The query had the `join` keyword in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting many values in subquery while should be just one.

try use `LIMIT 1` inside subquery will solve it. or you have to select value what you need but it must be one value.

```
  SELECT person_per.per_ID as AddToCart         ,       (SELECT .......)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- you selecting 1value here     ^^^^^^
                                                         |____you should select here also one value
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what the issue is, I am just looking for a way to resolve it whilst not losing the extra data in the query. For future reference where would the LIMIT 1 arg go in the statement?